# Python tkinter use canvas to create dynamically window with scroll bar

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter.scrollbar

My objective is to solve the problem of the grid exceeding the window(shown as figure.1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOGwb.jpg)

My program function is creating a grid that number of columns defined by user.

I tried using canvas to solve this problem, but it still doesn't work successfully.
It doesn't show the full grid in the canvas.(shown as figure.2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TrRj.jpg)

Below is my code, could you please help solve the problems or give me some advice.
Thanks a lot.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog

MainWindow = tk.Tk()

MainWindow.title('Helloworld')
MainWindow.geometry('1000x800')

def btn_generate():
    global EntryNamelist
    global Entrycoordinatelist
    global EntryLabellist
    con_num = en_condition_num.get()
    if con_num != '':
        #### Grid Body
        for i in range(1,int(con_num) +1 ):
                lb_name = tk.Label(fm_grid, text="Condition" + str(i) )
                lb_name.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=2, pady=1, ipadx=20, ipady=5)  
                En_name = tk.Entry(fm_grid, bd = 2,width = 10,font=('Ubuntu', 10))
                En_name.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=2, pady=1, ipadx=35, ipady=5) 
                En_coor = tk.Entry(fm_grid, bd = 2,width = 10,font=('Ubuntu', 10))
                En_coor.grid(row=i, column=2, padx=2, pady=1, ipadx=200, ipady=5)

    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please input a num of conditions")

fm_main = tk.Frame()
fm3 = tk.Frame(fm_main)
lb_condition = tk.Label(fm3,text = 'Please input the number of condition')
lb_condition.pack(side="left")
en_condition_num = tk.Entry(fm3, bd = 2,width = 5)
en_condition_num.pack()
fm3.pack()

btn_generate = tk.Button(fm_main,text="Generate Grid",command=btn_generate)
btn_generate.pack()
lb_en = tk.Label(fm_main,text = '')
lb_en.pack()

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200)

canvas=tk.Canvas(fm_main)
fm_grid = tk.Frame(canvas)
fm_grid.pack()
myscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(fm_main,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((4,4),window=fm_grid,anchor='nw')
fm_grid.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
fm_main.pack()
MainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried making the canvas bigger? You're forcing it to be a small size, and/or use options to `pack` to cause the canvas and frames to fill the space given to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: It doesn't show the full grid in the canvas

You have to sync, the `width` of the `Canvas` with the `width` of the `Frame` inside.

> **Note**: `fm_grid = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='blue')` is shown in `'blue'`.

[image]

---

> **Dont's**:
>   Remove `fm_grid.pack()`, you layout with: `canvas.create_window(...`.
>   Also, i recommend **not** to use a offset `(4, 4)`, because you have to calculate with this offset on every `canvas.configure(..., width=width + 4`. **Use `(0, 0)` instead**.
>
> ```
> # fm_grid.pack()
> ...
> canvas.create_window((4,4),window=fm_grid,anchor='nw')
> ```

---

> **Useless**, to create dynamically window:

- Your usage of `canvas.bbox` is useless, because it's the dimension you want to layout this widget.
- Using a fixed `width=200`, smaller than `fm_grid.width` will **allways cut** the `fm_grid` content, it's **not dynamically** either.

  > ```
  >   canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=200,height=200)
  > ```

---

> **How to sync the `width` of the `Canvas` with the `width` of the `Frame` inside?**

- You bound `fm_grid.bind("<Configure>"`, therefore the `event.widget` **is** `fm_grid`, the `Frame` inside.
- Get the dimensions of the `event.widget` from there `w.winfo_...` and build a `bbox` tuple to set `scrollregion`.
- Use `width` to set `canvas.width`, to be in sync with the `event.widget.winfo_width()`.

  ```
  class ScrollCanvas(tk.Canvas):
      def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

      def create_window(self, child):
          super().create_window((0, 0), window=child, anchor='nw')
          child.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)

      def on_configure(self, event):
          w = event.widget        
          bbox = x, y, width, height = 0, 0, w.winfo_width(), w.winfo_height()
          self.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=width)
  ```

  ***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: Hi stovfl,
Thank you for making such a wonderful answer!
Sorry, I'm a beginner in python.
I got a new problem after I change the function "myfunction" to "on_configure".

Comment: The error message like below.

"fm_grid.bind("<Configure>",on_configure)" 

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: on_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Comment: ***`TypeError: on_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' `***: I'm using `OOP`, therefore `def on_configure(self, event):` is a `class methode` which requires `self` as the first parameter. You are using functional programming, remove `self` and you will be fine.